# Closed form expression for $Tr\left[ (\mathbf{DW})^k \right]$

Tags: matrices, approximation-theory, closed-form-expressions

Given the $N \times N$ diagonal matrices $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ as defined below

$
\begin{split}
\mathbf{DW} &=
\left[
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \beta_{1} & 0 & \cdots & 0  \\
        0 & \beta_{2} & \cdots & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
        0 &  0 & \cdots & \beta_{N} \\
 \end{array} 
    \right]
%
\left[
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  M & \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{1,2}}} & \cdots & \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{1,N}}}  \\
        \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{2,1}}} & M & \cdots & \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{2,N}}}\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
        \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{N,1}}} &  \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}{\mbox{e}^{-i m \pi \theta_{N,2}}} & \cdots & M \\
 \end{array} 
    \right]
    \end{split}
$

where $\theta_{i,j} = \theta_{j,i}$ and $\theta_{i,j} = 0$ when $i = j$.

I would like to know if there is a closed form for 
\begin{equation}
Tr\left[ (\mathbf{DW})^k \right],
\end{equation}
where $Tr[.]$ is the matrix trace operator and $k$ is an integer greater than or equal to 1.

So far I have been able to manually find up to $Tr\left[ (\mathbf{DW})^3 \right]$ but it gets too cumbersome for $k \geq 4$. But perhaps, hopefully, someone out there knows a closed form for this.

Comment: Are $\beta_i$ positive? If so, once you diagonalise $W$, you'll get the answer as 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948061/eigenvalues-of-the-product-of-a-diagonal-and-a-symmetric-matrix

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580891/how-do-i-prove-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-to-its-kth-power-is-equal-to-the-sum

Comment: yes, $\beta_{k}, \forall k$ are positive.

Comment: @TomekKania, how could I find the eigen values? Thanks

Comment: I do believe it would be easier to get $Tr[(DW)^k]$ than calculating the eigenvalues, wouldn't it?